# How do i create a view like this in react native

Tags: android, react-native

How do I create a view like in an image shown below? The images should be stacked on each other and no. of images will be dynamic(2-5 images).

[image]

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can do it with absolute position and zIndex value in the style of the images.

Answer (score 0):

please try in this way , don't mind about styling you can separate it

```
    <View style={{width:'100%',height:'35%',backgroundColor:'#fff'}}>
                <View style={{width:50,height:50,borderRadius:50/2,position:'absolute',left:40,overflow:'hidden',elevation:5}}>
                    <Image source={require('image path')}style={{width:'100%',height:'100%',resizeMode:'cover',}} />
                </View>
                <View 
                style={{width:50,height:50,borderRadius:50/2,position:'absolute',left:20,overflow:'hidden',elevation:5}}>
                     <Image source={require('image path')}style={{width:'100%',height:'100%',resizeMode:'cover',}} />
                </View>
                <View style={{width:50,height:50,borderRadius:50/2,position:'absolute',overflow:'hidden',elevation:5}}>
                <Image source={require('image path')}style={{width:'100%',height:'100%',resizeMode:'cover',}} />
                </View>
            </View>
```